# Mysql variable reset back to default value automatically

Tags: mysql, linux, cpanel, whm

We have configured website over linux server and over MYSQL database,
and we have removed `only_full_group_by` variable from sql mode, but it again reset back to sql mode after specific period time.

Can anyone have idea behind this for possible reason

Comment: Pretty vague "after specific period time."

Comment: *we have removed only_full_group_by variable from sql mode* Where this setting was removed from? Settings file? service/daemon command line?

Comment: If you need this setting to be disabled for your application then adjust your connection settings in the application and add according statement into connection initialization code.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this even related to programming itself?

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html

**Setting the SQL Mode**

The default SQL mode in MySQL 8.0 includes these modes: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, and NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.

To set the SQL mode at server startup, use the --sql-mode="modes" option on the command line, or sql-mode="modes" in an option file such as my.cnf (Unix operating systems) or my.ini (Windows). modes is a list of different modes separated by commas. To clear the SQL mode explicitly, set it to an empty string using --sql-mode="" on the command line, or sql-mode="" in an option file.